Is there a scale function (ie 1:100 rather than changing the page size) for PDF within iText?
enter code hereI've been trying to print a set of CAD drawings to file using iText and then set some specific things like page labels and outlines (bookmarks) etc. I've been unable to find any documentation about setting a viewport and a drawing scale for each page. For clarity, when talking about scale I'm refering to 1:100 or 1mm = 100mm etc. It seems this is related to defining a distance for each user unit.
// R Represents the scale ratio of the drawing as per ISO32000
measureDict.Put(new PdfName("R"), new PdfString("1 mm = 10 mm")); //Alternative scales "1 cm = 1m", "10 cm = 5m", "1 mm = 20 mm"

// Add the /TargetUnitConversion field
// This represents the conversion of the units in the scale above. Only the units
// not the magnitude or scale factor. ie 2.54/72/100 for cm to m or 25.4/72 for mm to mm.
measureDict.Put(new PdfName("TargetUnitConversion"), new PdfNumber(0.3527778));

PdfDictionary dDict = new PdfDictionary();
dDict.Put(PdfName.Type, new PdfName("NumberFormat"));
dDict.Put(PdfName.U, new PdfString("m")); // Unit of measurement for /D    
dDict.Put(PdfName.C, new PdfNumber(1));
dDict.Put(PdfName.D, new PdfNumber(100));
dDict.Put(new PdfName("SS"), new PdfString("")); // Example value for /SS

PdfDictionary xDict = new PdfDictionary();
xDict.Put(PdfName.Type, new PdfName("NumberFormat"));
xDict.Put(PdfName.U, new PdfString("mm")); // Unit of measurement for /X
xDict.Put(PdfName.C, new PdfNumber(3.5277778)); // This represents 25.4/72 * 10 (scale factor)
xDict.Put(PdfName.D, new PdfNumber(100)); // Higher denominator for precision
xDict.Put(new PdfName("SS"), new PdfString("")); // Example value for /SS


Do you mean the scale representing the length of one user unit when printed on paper? Or do you mean the scale representing what a certain distance on paper corresponds to on the real object?

Thanks everybody for your responses.
Not looking to change the size of the PDF or the sheet, generally they're print at A0 or A1 as mentioned. When engineers are using the PDFs, we like to manually check dimensions and mark up the drawings. To do this we have to set a scale for the page (usually 1:100 or 1:20 for details etc). This can be done manually but it's tedious and needs to be done often. Ideally, once the drawings are printed a script can manually prescribe the scale for the page.
The short question is can you use iText to prescribe set measurement (ie 10mm) for each user unit?

Thanks KJ, I have looked at it, it's what I'm trying to achieve but I'm trying to get iText to do it for me. I have the information of what scales are required on each page through Revit/CAD so I want to assign them to each page so the user doesn't have to do it manually.

Thanks for your responses K J. The viewer is bluebeam and it definitely supports that functionality (in the exact same way as Adobe in your previous example). The difficulty from a user perspective is constantly having to change it manually (or not having it set at all) and over 200 drawings in a a pdf and then it constantly being set by the user etc. Having it done automatically as part of the print process would be a huge benefit in the process. Scaling the sheet up doesn't add the 'measuring' scale that I'm looking for. Appreciate your efforts to help though.

It seems to be something to do with viewports, user units and setting a dimension or distance between the user units, in the case of 1:100 it would be measure something like 10mm between each user unit.

This is the text from PDF32000
PDF documents, such as those created by CAD software, may contain graphics that are intended to represent real-world objects. Users of such documents often require information about the scale and units of measurement of the corresponding real-world objects and their relationships to units in PDF user space.
Beginning with PDF 1.6, such information may be stored in a measure dictionary. Measure dictionaries provide information about measurements units associated with a rectangular areas of the document known as a viewport.

So, as above, need to understand if there's some documentation around viewports and measurement dictionaries available.

Well, the documentation is the PDF specification ISO 32000 which you already referred to, either part should do. As far as I know there is no high level method in iText returning that scale, so you'll have to use the low level methods to extract the data. Is there anything specific you do not understand in the specification?

Thanks MKL. I’m using iText for Outlines and Page Labels but if I understand you correctly, implementing 3200 is a different library??

I’m not familiar with how to use low level methods to apply the information.

"I’m using iText for Outlines and Page Labels but if I understand you correctly, implementing 3200 is a different library??" - ISO 32000 is the full PDF specification but most libraries don't have detailed, dedicated APIs for all aspects of it. In particular specialized stuff like viewport and measure dictionaries often only can be read and written using Get and Put methods for arbitrary dictionary objects. I don't know which libraries do have explicit API support for measurement and viewports

"I’m not familiar with how to use low level methods to apply the information." - In that case I propose you should get a feeling for that by a step-by-step approach with a debugger and some example documents: First retrieve the VP array from the dictionary of a page that has that entry and inspect in a debugger. Then iterate over that array of viewport dictionaries and retrieve the Measure dictionary from each of them, again inspecting them in a debugger. Then retrieve the X and Y (if present) entries of these dictionaries and again inspect them. Always compare with the spec.

Thanks mkl, I’ll give that a go and post anything I find in here. Thanks for your help

@mkl I've managed to get this working for scales of 1:100 and 1:50 but am having no luck with scales 1:20 and 1:10. There appears to be a conversion or something similar missing.

Code updated above.

If you have a tool that can produce the pdf you want, maybe you should investigate the low level contents of that example so you can work out what you are missing?

Thanks @JeremyLakeman I have tried this and have set all the parameters to match those of a working PDF but something seems not to be working. The larger scales 1:200, 1:100 and 1:50 just seems to be an issue for smaller scales.

You may have to take the UserUnit value of the page into account, too, if present. It scales the user units in case of very large pages.
